# Full multiple HTML5 uploader with drag&drop, resize and rename

Tags: php, html, upload, drag-and-drop, image-resizing

I'm currently creating a website for a karate school with an administration but I'm stuck at the "Add photo" section.

I want to know how I can create a fully HTML5 picture uploader with drag & drop feature, resize to make a thumbnail, and rename the picture to fit the PHP specifications.

Here's my specifications for the uploader:

```
-> Drag and Drop from a local folder
-> If the image is not the correct ratio, provide a image cropping. (Like Twitter)
-> Resizing like this:
    -> Detect the aspect ratio (4:3 / 16:9)
    -> Create a thumb of 40% of the size
-> Create 2 files in the "Uploads" folder
    -> {a random ID}.{png,jpg,gif,etc...} (full size)
    -> {the same ID-thumb.{the same ext} (thumbnail)
```

I want to create this using only JS and PHP. I use Zend Framework for this app.

I hope that this is possible in PHP and HTML5 but I didn't try anything yet. I don't want to loose time because I'm paid for that so the time is cash!

Comment: Simply use google, there's many HTML5 drag and drop picture upload tutorials ;)

Answer (score 1):

For HTML Upload, You can surely use [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php), I have used it and it worked fine.

For re-sizing and thumb generation you may create your custom function and integrate that
into plupload or may go for [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)

Comment: plupload now supports resizing too. Available under GPLv2.